# Symfony 503 Service Unavailable on production

Tags: php, symfony

I just sent my symfony project on production, but it directly returned me an error : "503 Service Unavailable". Does someone know what could be the problem ? 
Thank you

Comment: Check logs for more information about the problem.

Comment: the logs file is empty

Comment: Where did you look? It can't be empty.

Comment: I looked in the ftp in the files online

Comment: You need to check server logs, not Symfony's

Comment: okay ! how can I check that ? Knowing that I have two other websites in the same server which are perfeclty working. And that if I delete the whole symfony project and push an index.html with "hello world" instead, it works

Comment: How can I know? I don't know anything about neither your environment nor configuration.

Comment: Sorry, I'm working with linux ubuntu

Comment: It's now about OS here. It's about webserver. You should know how is your werbserver configured, therefore you should know where to look into logs. That's all.

Comment: I can't find any logs file in my server

Answer (score 3):

On linux check the server log it is ussualy /var/logs/apache2 or just var/logs ..but in most of the cases it is an issue with cache clear